# What does the "deprecated in C++98" indicate?

Tags: c++, streambuf

The quotation below is seen at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream):

> std::strstreambuf
>
> | Defined in header `<strstream>` |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | class strstreambuf : public [std::basic_streambuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) | (deprecated in C++98) |

What does the `(deprecated in C++98)` indicate?

Does it mean that the above constructor of `std::strstreambuf`  is deprecated to be used in `C++98` and afterwards?

If that's is true, it seems that `std::strstreambuf` also should not be used since there is only one constructor for `std::strstreambuf`  and you have no other choice.

As far as I can see, it has nothing to do with the **[`C++ attribute: deprecated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated)**.

Comment: It's said very clearly in the notes: `strstream has been deprecated since C++98, std::stringstream and boost::iostreams::array are the recommended replacements.`

Comment: @shawn Any reference? Where did you see this statement?

Comment: The full story is:

strstream was deprecated in C++98:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream 

It says: 
* It essentially wraps a raw array I/O device implementation (std::strstreambuf) 
* Notes: strstream has been deprecated since C++98, std::stringstream and boost::iostreams::array are the recommended replacements.

Comment: The term "deprecated" in the C++ standard essentially means "slated for removal from a future version of the C++ standard".  Deprecation is about encouraging, not forcing, use of alternatives and the time from deprecation to removal can be short or long (and compiler/library vendors may elect to support removed features anyway).   By using a deprecated feature you run the risk of your code ceasing to build or to not work as intended when your compiler/library is updated after a feature is removed from the standard.

Comment: @Peter -- "deprecated" is weaker than "slated for removal". All it means is that it **might** be removed in the future. **If** you use it and it gets removed later you've got no basis to complain, because you were warned.